# how to config jmockit javaagent in gradle-kotin-dsl

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

**How do i config jmokit javaagent in gradle-kotin-dsl.**

I tried the follow example,but it doesn't work.

In file build.gradle.kts,the follow syntax to config javaagent is wrong.

```
tasks {
  test {
    jvmArgs("-javaagent:${classpath.find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }.absolutePath}");
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to write correctly with gradle-kotlin-dsl.

Answer (score 1):

In gradle-kotin-dsl, u can do this to config jmockit as javaagent.

```
tasks { 
  test { 
    jvmArgs("-javaagent:" + configurations.testRuntimeClasspath.get().find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }?.absolutePath);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In gradle-kotin-dsl, u can do this to config jmockit as javaagent.

tasks {
test {
jvmArgs("-javaagent:" + configurations.testRuntimeClasspath.get().find { it.name.contains("jmockit") }?.absolutePath);
}
}